# How To Update WordPress Database Fields in Ultimate Member Addon

Tags: database, wordpress, custom-fields

I want to update two custom fields in the database which are stored in wp-options -> um_cache_userdata_* <- * = userid

the column the data is stored in is named `option_value`
[image: screenshot]
I tried something like

```
global $wpdb;   
$posts = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID, license_keys FROM wp_options WHERE option_value = '".um_user('ID')."'");

   // Echo the title of the first scheduled post
   echo $posts;
```

The two values i want to change within option_values are the msn and test

```
s:8:"username";s:3:"msn";
s:12:"license_keys";s:4:"test";
```

Error Message: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method wpdb::get_row() in /home/firemax/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:5869

SIDENOTE: I've also tried

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_col( um_user('license_keys') );
```

which returns "Array" to the screen

Answer (score 0):

See user sa_ha_dum's answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125023/update-a-value-in-wordpress-wp-options)

Here are the references for this issue

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand the solution still I cant get it to work

Comment: Can you help with and example updating these fields `s:8:"username";s:3:"msn";
s:12:"license_keys";s:4:"test";`